# Coroutines and Retrofit, best way to handle Errors

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android-extensions

After reading this issue [How to deal with exception](https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter/issues/3) and this Medium [Android Networking in 2019 — Retrofit with Kotlin’s Coroutines](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-networking-in-2019-retrofit-with-kotlins-coroutines-aefe82c4d777) I've created my solution which consist in a `BaseService` capable of making the retrofit call and forward the results and exceptions down the "chain":

**API**

```
@GET("...")
suspend fun fetchMyObject(): Response<List<MyObject>>
```

**BaseService**

```
protected suspend fun <T : Any> apiCall(call: suspend () -> Response<T>): Result<T> {
    val response: Response<T>
    try {
        response = call.invoke()
    } catch (t: Throwable) {
        return Result.Error(mapNetworkThrowable(t))
    }
    if (!response.isSuccessful) {
        return Result.Error...
    }
    return Result.Success(response.body()!!)
}
```

**ChildService**

```
suspend fun fetchMyObject(): Result<List<MyObject>> {
    return apiCall(call = { api.fetchMyObject() })
}
```

**Repo**

```
    suspend fun myObjectList(): List<MyObject> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            when (val result = service.fetchMyObject()) {
                is Result.Success -> result.data
                is Result.Error -> throw result.exception
            }
        }
    }
```

**Note:** sometimes we need more than throwing an exception or one type of success result. To handle those situations this is how we can achieve that:

```
sealed class SomeApiResult<out T : Any> {
    object Success : SomeApiResult<Unit>()
    object NoAccount : SomeApiResult<Unit>()
    sealed class Error(val exception: Exception) : SomeApiResult<Nothing>() {
        class Generic(exception: Exception) : Error(exception)
        class Error1(exception: Exception) : Error(exception)
        class Error2(exception: Exception) : Error(exception)
        class Error3(exception: Exception) : Error(exception)
    }
}
```

And then in our ViewModel:

```
when (result: SomeApiResult) {
    is SomeApiResult.Success -> {...}
    is SomeApiResult.NoAccount -> {...}
    is SomeApiResult.Error.Error1 -> {...}
    is SomeApiResult.Error -> {/*all other*/...}
}
```

More about this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60641763/sealed-class-for-repository-to-viewmodel-comunication).

**BaseViewModel**

```
protected suspend fun <T : Any> safeCall(call: suspend () -> T): T? {
    try {
        return call()
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        parseError(e)
    }
    return null
}
```

**ChildViewModel**

```
fun fetchMyObjectList() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        safeCall(call = {
            repo.myObjectList()
            //update ui, etc..
        })
    }
}
```

I think the `ViewModel` (or a `BaseViewModel`) should be the layer handling the exceptions, because in this layer lies the UI decision logic, for example, if we just want to show a toast, ignore a type of exception, call another function etc...

What do you think?

**EDIT:** I've created a [medium](https://medium.com/@guidelgado/coroutines-retrofit-and-a-nice-way-to-handle-responses-769e013ee6ef) with this topic

Answer (score 17):

> I think the ViewModel (or a BaseViewModel) should be the layer
> handling the exceptions, because in this layer lies the UI decision
> logic, for example, if we just want to show a toast, ignore a type of
> exception, call another function etc...
>
> What do you think?

Certainly, you are correct. The coroutine should fire on the `ViewModel` even though the logic is in the `Repository`/`Service`. That's why Google has already created a special `coroutineScope` called [viewModelScope](https://proandroiddev.com/usage-of-the-viewmodelscope-f28703467b31), otherwise it would be "repositoryScope" . Also coroutines have a nice feature on exception handling called the `CoroutineExceptionHandler`. This is where things get nicer because you don't have to implement a `try{}catch{}` block:

```
val coroutineExceptionHanlder = CoroutineExceptionHandler{_, throwable -> 
    throwable.printStackTrace()
    toastLiveData.value = showToastValueWhatever()
}
```

Later in the `ViewModel`

```
coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO + coroutineExceptionHanlder){
      val data = serviceOrRepo.getData()
}
```

Of course you can still use the `try/catch` block without the `CoroutineExceptionHandler`, free to choose.

Notice that in case of Retrofit you don't need the `Dispatchers.IO` scheduler because Retrofit does that for you (since Retrofit 2.6.0).

Anyways, I can't say the article is bad, but it is not the best solution. If you want to follow the articles' guide, you may want to check [Transformations on the LiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations).

EDIT:
What you need to know more, is that coroutines are not safe. What I mean with this is that they might cause memory leaks especially in Android lifecycle overall. You need a way to cancel coroutines while the `Activity`/`Fragment` doesn't live anymore. Since the `ViewModel` has the `onCleared` (which is called when `Activity`/`Fragment` is destroyed), this implies that coroutines should fire in one of them. And perhaps this is the main reason why you should start the coroutine in the `ViewModel`. Notice that with the `viewModelScope` there is no need to `cancel` a job `onCleared`.

A simple example:

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
   val data = getDataSlowly()
   withContext(Dispatchers.MAIN) {
      showData();
   }
}
```

or without the `viewModelScope` :

```
val job = Job()
val coroutineScope = CoroutineContext(Dispatchers.MAIN + job)

fun fetchData() {
   coroutineScope.launch() {
   val data = getDataSlowly()
       withContext(Dispatchers.MAIN) {
          showData();
       }
   }
}

//later in the viewmodel:

override fun onCleared(){
  super.onCleared()
  job.cancel() //to prevent leaks
}
```

Otherwise, your `Service`/`Repository` would leak. Another note is **NOT** [to use the `GlobalScope`](https://medium.com/@elizarov/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc) in this cases.

Comment: Thanks for your post. Actually as you can see in my sample code I'm using `viewModelScope` to make the repo call, which will use a `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` to call Retrofit. The only piece of code missing is the case where the activity is the one that start the call. In that case, I expose a `suspend fun` from the viewModel to be called inside a `lifecyleScope`. I guess this choices are correct consider your answer right? When you say Retrofit 2.6.0 uses `Dispatchers.IO` for me, that means that `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` inside my repo could be removed?

Comment: the activity will just hold a reference of the viewmodel and say: `myViewModel.fetchMyObjectList()` not as suspending but as a method. then inside the `fetchMyObjectList()` you can just `viewModelScope.launch`. Yes, if you have Retrofit 2.6+ and inside your coroutines are only retrofit calls, no need for `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`

Comment: Why shouldn't be inside `lifecycleScope`? I guess it may depend on the use case, but if I move away to other activity (we could have a problem when going into bg no?) and I want to cancel that network call. Putting it inside `lifecycleScope` wouldn't manage that for me? (I'm still learning how to work with coroutines, maybe I'm misinterpreted some concepts ^^)

Comment: That's fine with the `lifecycleScope` but the `View` mustn't know about your calls. The view is there just to render what the viewmodel gives. So you break the first part of the SOLID principles, the S

Comment: Yeah sure, I use `Data Binding` and all actions start inside the ViewModel, but there are some cases for instance `lifecycleScope.startWhenResumed{}` that have to start in the Activity. If a developer chooses to user `View Binding`those actions will start in the Activity also (`onClickListeners`, etc). Another question that I forgot to ask, you mention - correctly - CoroutineExceptionHandler. I've a BaseViewModel with `protected suspend fun <T : Any> safeCall(call: suspend () -> T): T?`which encapsulates the call inside a `try catch` block. Do I benefit from `CoroutineExceptionHandler`?

Comment: you can replace try/catch block with `CoroutineExceptionHandler` and it's still the same thing

Comment: In unit tests `viewModelScope` doesn't propagate the exceptions as test failures. When a call inside of `viewModelScope` throws an exception the test still passes, only displaying a message that exception has been thrown.  Because of that I had to go away from `viewModelScope` and instead inject `MainScope()` which later in tests can be replaced by `TestCoroutineScope()`.

Comment: hmmm check the docs in testing the `CoroutineExceptionHandler` I guess

Comment: Why do you need `Dispatchers.MAIN`?  Dispatchers.IO automatically switches to main thread.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to handle exceptions in repository and return a single response in the form of sealed class object to viewmodel. Keeping this in repository makes the repository as single source of truth and your code more 
clean & readable.

Comment: So what you are suggesting is to move the `return when (result)` from the `BaseService` into my `Repository` (this will make `BaseService` return just `result`) and process the data when `is Result.Success -> {...}` and forward the error with `is Result.Error -> throw result.exception`. Did I get it right? I'm going to edit my code ;)

Answer (score 1):

as a completion to @coroutineDispatcher excelent answer I would suggest catching the exception and check if it's HttpException, UnknownHostException or SocketException to give the user more feedback on the exception. for example

```
if (throwable is SocketException) {
     //very bad internet 
     return
}

if (throwable is HttpException) {
     // parse error body message from
     //throwable.response().errorBody()
     return
 }

if (throwable is UnknownHostException) {
     // probably no internet or your base url is wrong
     return
 }
 ShowSomethingWentWrong()
```

all the above code goes inside `coroutineExceptionHanlder`