# Sealed class for Repository to ViewModel comunication

Tags: android, kotlin, sealed-class

Based on this [post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/sealed-with-a-class-a906f28ab7b5) by Florina Muntenescu I have 2 questions:

**Question 1:** In the following situation considering a `Respository` response *SomeApiResult*:

```
sealed class SomeApiResult<out T : Any> {
    object Success : SomeApiResult<Unit>()
    object NoAccount : SomeApiResult<Unit>()
    sealed class Error(val exception: Exception) : SomeApiResult<Nothing>() {
        class Generic(exception: Exception) : Error(exception)
        class Error1(exception: Exception) : Error(exception)
        class Error2(exception: Exception) : Error(exception)
        class Error3(exception: Exception) : Error(exception)
    }
}
```

Latter when using `when` in my `ViewModel` I wont be able to do something like:

```
when (result: SomeApiResult) {
    ...
    is SomeApiResult.Error.Error1,
    is SomeApiResult.Error.Error2 -> {
        // it will fail with "Unresolved reference: exception"
        result.exception
    }
    is SomeApiResult.Error.Error3 -> {
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?
This is valid though:

```
when (result: Result<Int>) {
   ...
   is SomeApiResult.Error -> result.exception.message
}
```

**Question 2:** When creating the error response I have to create a *GenericError* because if I try to instantiate the `sealed class` I get an error. This is how I make it work:

```
is Result.Error ->
    when (result.exception) {
        is Error1 -> SomeApiResult.Error.Error1(result.exception)
        is Error2 -> SomeApiResult.Error.Error2(result.exception)
        ...
        else -> SomeApiResult.Error.Generic(result.exception)
    }
```

In my `ViewModel` I wont be querying for `Error.Generic`.
Instead, I'll use `is SomeApiResult.Error` as shown above (like `else ->` "other errors"). Is this the right way?